# Converting numeric column to range

Tags: data, excel

I have this data below. I want to convert temperature column into range of data like class interval and get the sum of sales in that range. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you are going to want to use an [Excel Pivot Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

**Step 1:** First, select the columns that you would like to include in the table (here your `temperature` and your `sales` column).

[image]

**Step 2:** Click the Insert tab and then click add Pivot Table.

[image]

**Step 3:** Click OK for adding the Pivot Table and then make sure to select both of the fields that you want to include. In this case, both the `temperature` and `sales` fields.

**NOTE:** Here, it is important that you make sure that the Rows box has the `temperature` field and the Values box has the `sales` field.

[image]

**Step 4:** Right click one of the values from your temperature column and click *Group*. This will show you the total range of the values you have. Select how many bins or 'intervals' that you would like to include.

[image]

**Step 5:** Click OK and then you have your Pivot Table.

[image]